# How can I fix the error " Variable-sized object may not be initialized "?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

How can I fix the error "Variable-sized object may not be initialized" with the following code:

```
sv A[i] =new sv(m,t,d,l,tl,ml,nh);
```

My code from the beginning to the error line:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class sv{ 
public: int msv; 
  string ten,lop; 
  float diem; 
  string tenlop, malop; 
  int namhoc; 
  sv(); 
  sv(int m,string t, float d,string l,string tl,string ml, int nh);
class lophoc{ 
public:
  lophoc(); 
  lophoc(string tl,string ml, int nh); };
  void hienthi(){
  cout<<msv<<"\t"<<ten<<"\t"<<diem<<"\t"<<tenlop<<"\t"<<malop<<"\t"<<namhoc<<"\n";
            }
 }; 
  sv::sv(){ }
  sv::sv(int m,string t, float d,string l,string tl,string ml, int nh)
  { 
    msv=m; ten=t; diem=d; lop=l; tenlop=tl; malop=ml, namhoc=nh; } 
int main(){ 
  sv A[100]; 
  int n,i,m,d,nh; 
  string t,tl,ml,l; 
  cin>>n; 
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
  cout<<"lan luot nhap ma sv,ten, diem,lop hoc: "; 
  cin>> m>>t>>d>>l; 
  cout<< "lan luot nhap ten lop, ma lop, nam hoc: "; 
  cin>>tl>>ml>>nh; 
  sv A[i] =new sv(m,t,d,l,tl,ml,nh);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
sv A[i] =new sv(m,t,d,l,tl,ml,nh);
```

looks like a declaration of another array of `sv` called `A` with run-time size of `i` to the compiler (A C99 feature). 
If you wanted to assign to the element at index `i`, you would do:

```
A[i] = sv(m,t,d,l,tl,ml,nh);
```

Note that `new` allocates on the heap and returns a pointer, which is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

You have already declared an array

```
sv A[100];
```

To fill in the array, just use

```
A[i] = sv(m,t,d,l,tl,ml,nh);
```